# Getting a strange output when using openAI gym render

Tags: python, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I've written a simple python code to simulate 'FrozenLake-v0':

```python
import gym

env = gym.make('FrozenLake-v0')
env.reset()

for _ in range(1000):
    env.render()
    env.step(env.action_space.sample())
```

However my output contains some special symbols:

```
[41mS[0mFFF
FHFH
FFFH
HFFG
  (Left)
[41mS[0mFFF
FHFH
FFFH
HFFG
  (Up)
S[41mF[0mFF
FHFH
FFFH
HFFG
  (Down)
SFFF
F[41mH[0mFH
FFFH
HFFG
...
```

Why are these symbols coming up in the output? 
How can I fix it?

EDIT:

When I'm making the environment, I get the following warning. I don't know if that's useful:

> [33mWARN: gym.spaces.Box autodetected dtype as class 'numpy.float32'.
>   Please provide explicit dtype.[0m

Answer (score 1):

The special symbols that you see (`[41m`, `[0m`, etc) are the **color directives** (see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17299/what-do-the-different-colors-mean-in-ls)), which make the board look nicer when the shell supports them. More concretely, the current agent position gets the red background.

Looking at openai-gym source code I don't see any flags to suppress the colors, so the best solution for you is to enable color support in your shell, so that these directives won't bother you. For example, take a look a [this discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148/colorizing-your-terminal-and-shell-environment) on Unix SE.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the warning by  executing `gym.logger.set_level(40)`. This will set minimal level of logger message to be printed to 40. Correspondingly, only **error** level messages will be displayed. You will need to include this statement every time you import `gym`.

Comment: @tk3 thanks for pointing out the typo. Should have accepted but didn't notice the change at first.

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting a gui? if that's the case you have to mention the `mode` while calling `env.render()` function. by setting `mode=human`, you invoke the render function in the gui mode. If this doesn't work, then it means the environment doesn't have a gui.